# Embed multiple youtube video from database to php

Tags: php, video, youtube

I have stored youtube video URL into database and retrieve from database and display on website using `<iframe>`. The first video is displayed well. However, the second and following videos unable to show on webpage.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM presentation  ORDER BY year DESC LIMIT 0, 5000");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo'<div class="col-md-4 text-dimension">';
    echo'<center><iframe width="250" height="200" src="'.$row['video_url'].'" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen></iframe></center>';
    echo'</div>';
    echo'<div class="col-md-8 text-dimension">';
    echo'<p class="lead"><span style="font-size: 15px;">';

    $id=$row['slide_id'];
    echo '<br><br><b>' .$row['title']. '</b><br>';
    echo 'Presenter :' .$row['presenter']. '<br>';
    echo '<a href=../isiti/presentation/?id='.$id.' style="font-size:12px;">[view slide]<br><br></a>';
    echo '<span class=right><a href="edit_form.php?id='.$id.'">[edit]</a>

    <a name="delete" id="delete" href="public_delete.php?id='.$id.'">[delete]</a></span><br>';
    echo'</p>';
    echo'</div>';
}
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code. Please help me to figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: if it exists, try to also provide the error message.. if you are using chrome, try to press `Ctrl+Shift+C` to show the console and let us know the error message..

Comment: Are the iframes there, just no video or are the iframes missing? You can verify with F12 (works for firefox, chrome, and ie) to show the code.

Comment: Refused to display 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4pher2dM4Dw' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

This is the error show in the console...

Answer (score 0):

When you get the link from youtube you must use the embed link they provide. This is the link you will store in your database so when you echo the $row['video_url'] it will load the entire html string from the database.

I think the error you are receiving is because you are using your iframe and trying to throw the link into it and youtube isn't wanting to play along with that.